# react & i18next, why do i need react-i18next

Tags: reactjs, i18next

I am new to i18next and I dont really understand why there is a need to use react-i18next when playing with react.

Using an external library like `moment.js` in my component i do : `const date = moment(this.state.date)`

Can I do the something like below with i18next :

```
import i18next from 'i18next';

const translated = () => (
 <h1>{i18next.t('title')}</h1>
)
```

Thanks

Comment: fyi: a newer react-i18next guide can be found here: https://dev.to/adrai/how-to-properly-internationalize-a-react-application-using-i18next-3hdb/stats

Comment: There's also a nice i18next crash course with a dedicated second part working with react-i18next: https://youtu.be/SA_9i4TtxLQ

Answer (score 3, accepted):

sure you can directly use i18next. react-i18next is only some optimization to use it in react -> eg. rerender on language change, or dynamic load of the namespaces using the hoc or render prop. Or the Trans component which allows you to nest react components into translations. But there is no magic, like there is no magic in jquery-i18next or vue-i18next -> it just simplifies your task.